# what is the additional information preserved in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage

What is the information chrome preserves in localstorage and is it possible to use in any case? Do other browsers preserve the same?
E.g. my console returned that on `localStorage` request(besides the objects I intentionally put there):

```
_at.hist.0607: "{"m":600,"k":2,"l":{"0":100,"1":42},"b":{"0":0,"1":1024,"2":0,"3":16,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0,"13":0,"14":0,"15":0,"16":0,"17":0,"18":0}}"

_at.hist.0609: "{"m":600,"k":2,"l":{"0":100,"1":42},"b":{"0":0,"1":1024,"2":0,"3":16,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0,"13":0,"14":0,"15":0,"16":0,"17":0,"18":0}}"
length: 7
se:fkey: "c122b51f4bd30fb5f605d53571e9e76d,1404789428"
yt-remote-connected-devices: "{"data":"[]","expiration":1402306854530,"creation":1402220454530}"
yt-remote-device-id: "{"data":"762ef7ce-f934-42cc-9abb-4647bf3bb68b","expiration":1430383329393,"creation":1398847329393}"
```

Comment: Those may have been added by any additional scripts you have in your page. Ex: google analytics.

Comment: ah, it may be AdBlock i guess...